# How to register map move / map pan events in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm looking for OpenLayer 3 map event for map move/map pan, something like:

```
map.on('move', function(){
  ...
}
```

Does anyone know how to implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

These events are no longer present in recent versions. Please refer to [the more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29709324/1240557) for an up-to-date information.

---

Names of the events you're looking for are `drag` and/or `dragend` (it's probably a better idea to depend on properties names, though: `ol.MapBrowserEvent.EventType.DRAG` but it didn't work on the demo page):

```js
map.on('drag', function() {
  console.log('Dragging...');
});

map.on('dragend', function() {
  console.log('Dragging ended.');
});
```

Reverse-engineered by looking inside `mapbrowserevent.js`, the documentation explicitly mentions events are not documented yet.

Comment: These events don't exist anymore. The ``drag`` event is renamed to ``pointerdrag`` and ``dragend`` doesn't exist anymore, but there is a ``moveend`` event now, which is similar.

Comment: I would have deleted the answer as obsolete but cannot as it's accepted.

Answer (score 12):

The `moveend` event might be the one you search for - it detects any move made, even those not invoked by dragging.

```js
map.on('moveend', function (e) {
    console.log("moved");
});
```

See http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html

Comment: Is it correct to assume there is no event fired while the map is moving?

Comment: link is down :(

Answer (score 1):

MoveEnd trigger if u move the map with a script.
I have use that in OpenLayers 6:

```
map.on('pointerdrag', function (event) {
    is_map_center = false;
})
```

hf gl!

Comment: Any idea how to simulate the pan with cypress?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this functionality exists in 2 functions within the View of a map, not the map itself. You can monitor the center property of the View by listening for `change:center` events. There is also a `getInteracting()` method in ol.View that will return a boolean if an interaction (zooming or panning) is occurring.

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.View.html#getInteracting